# Travelling to UK from India via Srilanka (Tourist Visa)

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, sri-lanka

I need to join my spouse who is studying in UK and I am currently in India. UK added India to the red list countries list - whcih means from India flights are very less and also I need to be in hotel quarantine for 10 days in UK.

1. I am planning to take a tourist visa to srilanka.
2. Be there in a hotel quarantine for 14 days -  I myself make sure that there is no health risk due to me travelling.
3. From Srilanka after 14 days I travel to UK.

However

1. Any risks?
2. Will the Visa officer demand a return ticket from Srilanka to India as I am on a tourist visa?
3. If so can I show a dummy ticket for the time being or can I say that I will book my return later?

Comment: Officers in Srilanka won't care as long as you are leaving the country. You can leave to UK or virtually any other country in the world.

Comment: One risk I can envisage is that Sri Lanka also gets added to the red list.

Comment: yes I agree that is a risk

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.